# Regex from 0.01 to 999.00

Tags: regex

I've been trying to create a regual expression to match all positive floats from 0.01 up to 999.00

Here's what I've managed to do so far: `^999$|^999.0$|^999.00$|^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

However, I need to exclude values like:

```
0
00
000
0.0
0.00
00.0
00.00
000.0
000.00
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what about val>0.01 and val<999.0? why do you need regex?

Comment: 001.10 it's allowed I just wanted to exclude zeros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a negative lookahead at the start.

```
^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)(?:999|999.0|999.00|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$
```

OR

```
^(?!(?:0+(?:\.0+)?|999\.\d*[1-9])$)(?:999|999.0|999.00|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sY4uC9/3)

`(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)` at the start forces the regex engine to not to match the lines which contain only 0's.

Comment: I've just noticed, my regex is matching 999.99 how can I cap it at 999.00?

Comment: Works great ..Thanks! @AvinashRaj